# How to output the methods from class

Tags: php

```
<?php
class A
    {
        public $attribute1;
        function operation1()
            {
                echo 'operation1';
            }
}
$a = new A();
var_dump($a);
```

It shows:

```
object(A)[1]
  public 'attribute1' => null
```

Question:

It outputs the property in `class A`, but if I want to see the methods/functions in `class A`, how could I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can gets the class methods' names

```
$class_methods = get_class_methods('A');
// or
$class_methods = get_class_methods(new A());

foreach ($class_methods as $method_name) {
    echo "$method_name\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [get_class_methods](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php) to view the class function names.

```
$class_methods = get_class_methods(new A());

foreach ($class_methods as $method_name) {
    echo "$method_name\n";
}
```

## Output

```
operation1
```

Comment: yes, I can see the names, but is there a way that I can see the contents inside the method? such as `echo 'operation1';`

Comment: @user2507818 I don't think that `PHP` is having any kind of function that will return code of `function`. But anyways you should be interested on result rather than code of function.